# What is the right cloud service(s) for real-time streaming and backtesting applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I wish to record time series data at a very high frequency. I am wondering if there is a elegant serverless solution that allows me to store, and react to real-time data.

I want to use stored data to create statistical models, and then I want to process new data in real-time based on those models.

AWS Kinesis streams seems to fit the bill - however, I am unsure if it is only for reacting in real time, or if it also collects historical data that I might be able to use offline to build models.

Google DataFlow and Pub/Sub also seem to be relevant, but not sure if it would be appropriate for the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with AWS, you might use **Kinesis** and **EMR** to achieve your goal. Firstly you can create a delivery stream in fully managed **Kinesis Firehose** and route it to **S3 or Redshift** to collect historical data.

Once your data is on S3, you may do the statistical analysis by pointing the S3 bucket to an EMR job to process fresh data that s3 receive. Read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-kinesis-firehose-simple-highly-scalable-data-ingestion/) article for more information.

On EMR managed hadoop framework, you may setup **Open-Source R and RStudio** for statistical analysis if you will. Here is [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/statistical-analysis-with-open-source-r-and-rstudio-on-amazon-emr/) on that.

Answer (score 1):

We accomplished this using Kinesis with Flink ( from apache ) . Flink is really very scalable solution.